# agregar fila a tabla HTML con JQuery en el Tbody

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Como puedo agregar una fila a una tabla HTML con JQuery? tengo el siguiente código pero lo que hace es agregar una fila en la parte de thead de mi tabla y el objetivo es que se agregue en el tbody.

```
 function agregarFila(Id, Nombres, ApellidoP, AppellidoM) {
   var htmlTags = '<tr><td>' + Id + '</td><td>' + 
       Nombres + '</td><td>' + ApellidoP + '</td><td>' + 
       AppellidoM + '</td></tr>';
   $('#tablaprueba tr:last').after(htmlTags);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utiliza la función append() de JQuery y cambia el selector a $('#tablaprueba tbody') como el ejemplo

```js
function agregarFila(Id, Nombres, ApellidoP, AppellidoM) {
   
   var htmlTags = '<tr>'+
        '<td>' + Id + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + Nombres + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + ApellidoP + '</td>'+
        '<td>' + AppellidoM + '</td>'+
      '</tr>';
      
   $('#tablaprueba tbody').append(htmlTags);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablaprueba">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nombres</th>
      <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
      <th>Apellido Materno</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias!! Era justo lo que necesitaba